# Using line.replace twice in the same line

Tags: python, performance

I am trying to use line.replace such that I can replace two separate variables in the same line before moving onto the next line.

lets say the text file "file.txt' is:

(1.00)

(2.00)

(3.00)

I would like to replace the ( and ) with and empty space for each line. Here is what I have.

```
file=open('file.txt', 'r')
file_1=open('file_1.txt', 'w')

for line in file:
  x=line.replace('(', "")
  file_1.writelines(x)

file_2=open('file_1.txt', 'r')
file_3=open('file_2.txt', 'w')

for line in file_2:
  y=line.replace(')', "")
  file_3.writelines(y)
```

Is there a way to make this more efficient?

Thank you for your help,

Kyle

Comment: This is the most inefficient way.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to call the replace function a second time after you do it the first time:

```
for line in file:
    x=line.replace('(', "")
    x=x.replace(')', "")
    file_1.writelines(x)
```

Or, you could even call the replace function twice on the same line:

```
for line in file:

    x=line.replace('(', "").replace(')', "")

    file_1.writelines(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make this much simpler.  As others have said, you can call replace twice, because it does return a string, so you could do...

```
for line in file:
  x=line.replace('(', "").replace(')', "")
  file_1.writelines(x)
```

You don't actually need the x either, so you can combine them into one line.  The works because the replace function keeps returning a string.

```
for line in file:
  file_1.writelines(line.replace('(', "").replace(')', ""))
```

And now that it's a one line for loop, we can make this even simpler into a list comprehension.  Making the entire program

```
file=open('file.txt', 'r')
file_1=open('file_1.txt', 'w')
[file_1.writelines(line.replace('(', "").replace(')', "")) for line in file]
```

Don't hesitate to ask questions.